# updateMany mongoose with multiple condition

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have two documents as in db bookingDetails" as:

```
{
    "_id":ObjectId("12jj21jan21jdo3kan2idm11"),
    "book_status":"BOOKED",
    "reservation":false,
}

{
    "_id":ObjectId("12jj21jan21jdo3kan2idm11"),
    "book_status":"ACCEPTED",
    "reservation":true,
}
```

update both of the document with multiple queries.

I am trying as,

```
bookingDetails.updateMany(
    {
        "book_status":"ACCEPTED",
    },
    {
         $set:{
             "book_status":"DONE"
         }
    }
)

bookingDetails.updateMany(
    {
        "book_status":"BOOKED",
    },
    {
         $set:{
             "book_status":"DONE"
         }
    }
)
```

But this method is repetitive which increases load on db. Is there any way that it can be optimized?

Please let me know if anyone needs any further information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) like this:

```
bookingDetails.updateMany({
  "$or": [
    {
      "book_status": "ACCEPTED"
    },
    {
      "book_status": "BOOKED"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "$set": {
    "book_status": "DONE"
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6J5laeJluaj)